# Do all packages under Axis come under apache license?

Tags: licensing, gpl, cddl

I am trying to find what license is used by axis-wsdl4j here - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/axis/axis-wsdl4j

Since no license was listed I looked at axis license:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis
Here it clearly lists that it is using Apache license.

Since axis-wsdl4j appears to be a subset of axis, is it safe to assume axis-wsdl4j  also uses Apache ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't blindly trust any website concerning licensing for a software package.

Always find the origin, and see what they have to say about it.

To answer the question, the license for WSDL4J is [Common Public License v1.0](https://opensource.org/licenses/cpl1.0.txt), per [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22369159/8507637), which points to the [WSDL4J SourceForge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j).

The [sources](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/files/WSDL4J/1.6.3/wsdl4j-src-1.6.3.zip) available there contain the following license file, (wsdl4j-src-1.6.3/wsdl4j-1_6_3/license.html).

```
Common Public License - v 1.0

THE ACCOMPANYING PROGRAM IS PROVIDED UNDER THE TERMS OF THIS COMMON PUBLIC LICENSE ("AGREEMENT"). ANY USE, REPRODUCTION OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE PROGRAM CONSTITUTES RECIPIENT'S ACCEPTANCE OF THIS AGREEMENT.

[ . . . TRUNCATED . . . ]
```